# Expose Both Ports 8080 and 3000 For Cloud Run Deployment

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, containers, google-cloud-run

**TL:DR** - I am trying to deploy my MERN stack application to GCP's Cloud Run. Struggling with what I believe is a port issue.

My React application is in a `client` folder **inside of my Node.js** application.

Here is my one `Dockerfile` to run both the front-end and back-end:

```
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./

# Installing components for be connector
RUN npm install --silent  
WORKDIR /app/client
RUN npm install --silent

WORKDIR /app
RUN chmod +x /app/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT [ "/app/entrypoint.sh" ]
```

... and here is my `entrypoint.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/sh
node /app/index.js &
cd /app/client
npm start
```

`docker-compose up` works locally, and `docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 3000:3000 <image_id>` runs the image I built. Port 8080 is for Node and port 3000 for the React app. However, on Cloud Run, the app does not work. When I visit the app deployed to Cloud Run, the frontend initially loads for a split second, but then the app crashes as it attempts to make requests to the API.

[image]
In the **Advanced Settings**, there is a container port which defaults to 8080. I've tried changing this to 3000, but neither works. I cannot enter 8080,3000, as the field takes valid integers only for the port. Is it possible to deploy React + Node at the same time to Cloud Run like this? How can I have Cloud Run listen on both 8080 and 3000, as opposed to just 1 of the 2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not currently possible.

Instead, you can [run multiple processes inside Cloud Run](https://ahmet.im/blog/cloud-run-multiple-processes-easy-way/), but instead use nginx to proxy requests between them depending on the URL, similar to what's recommended in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49779721/328036).

Comment: Hmmm okay. Would I be better off simply having separate docker images and separate cloud runs for node and react?

Comment: Possibly, it's a tradeoff between more configuration in a single container vs having a duplicated deploy process for two separate services.

Comment: It's generally a better idea to split different processes into different containers. Sadly, forking an app into background like `foo &` inside a container is a malicious usage pattern that has many downsides. I discuss some of these in my blog post https://ahmet.im/blog/minimal-init-process-for-containers/.