# Is it posible to expose 5001 (HTTP) and 5672 (TCP) ports in a Cloud Run Service?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, rabbitmq, google-cloud-run, webapi

I am setting up a solution in Google Cloud. I need a RabbitMQ queue broker and a WebAPI developed in .NET Core 2.2. The idea is for the WebAPI to connect to RabbitMQ to receive messages.

I have mounted RabbitMQ with GKE in a cluster of kubernetes with RabbitMQ Cluster, obtained in Marketplace. I have mounted the WebAPI in Cloud Run. Both components are raised in a standard way, without any particularity for publication.

The WebAPI uses port 5001 for HTTP traffic, and apparently the listener that subscribes to RabbitMQ to receive messages uses port 5672.

The problem is that uploading the WebAPI to Cloud Run doesn't work, apparently because Cloud Run only exposes one port for HTTP traffic and therefore the other port, 5672, is blocked.

By mounting the same WebAPI in a container on kubernetes, it does expose port 5001 and 5672 and works fine.

Can a WebAPI be published to Cloud Run that, in addition to exposing port 5001 for HTTP traffic, also exposes port 5672 (in this case to open a TCP connection) and thus be able to connect to RabbitMQ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expose Both Ports 8080 and 3000 For Cloud Run Deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61355416/expose-both-ports-8080-and-3000-for-cloud-run-deployment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Cloud Run (fully managed) always exposes services a single port (on :443) over HTTPS.

Comment: And would there be a way to have a container in Cloud Run listening to a RabbitMQ queue? I have tried to change the open Cloud Run port to 5672, but the container dies as soon as it wakes up, possibly because when not attending to HTTP requests for that port, it cannot respond to the CloudRun healthcheck.

Comment: No. That's not the application model Cloud Run is designed for. If RabbitMQ can push over HTTP, then it would work.