# Google Cloud Run - how to specify docker command line arguments for GCR?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-run

I have a Docker container that has a Flask server inside ran with Gunicorn.
Locally I run it using `docker run -p 443:443 appcontainer` and it works just fine.
I can't figure out how to tell Google Cloud Run to do the same, is it possible to specify the `-p` for it or any other Docker command line arguments for that matter?

Comment: Is the service serve HTTP or HTTPS request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Docker documentation
[Published ports](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/)

> By default, when you create or run a container using docker create or
> docker run, it does not publish any of its ports to the outside world.
> To make a port available to services outside of Docker, or to Docker
> containers which are not connected to the container’s network, use the
> --publish or -p flag. This creates a firewall rule which maps a container port to a port on the Docker host to the outside world

Cloud Run (fully managed) always exposes services a single port (on :443) over HTTPS [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61893589/is-it-posible-to-expose-5001-http-and-5672-tcp-ports-in-a-cloud-run-service) and cloud run container  listen on default port 8080. From my understanding the default set up is something like (`-p 443:8080`).

However you can configure on which port requests are sent to the container if you want to change the default port `8080`

[Configuring the container port](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/containers#command-line)

```
gcloud run services update SERVICE --port 443
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed! As always, docs had it.. hehe